# Converting double click to touch

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, click, touch

I am trying to implement the following Jquery:

```
 <script>
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.flexslider li a').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = this.href;
        return false;
    });

});
  }
</script>
```

On a desktop when the user agent is removed this behaves as it should and ensure double click is required to visit a link. This however is not working on mobile and I am assuming its due to the function being a touch rather then click?

Does anyone know of a way to adapt this code to ensure double tap is required to visit a link on a Lumia device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

Use this code to detect device is false or true

Comment: Thanks, it is detecting the device fine its just not applying double click/tap to go to hyperlink!

Comment: remove "return false" in dblclick event. So only location will change.

Comment: wont change the fact that the user still goes though to hyperlink on first touch

Comment: Use e.preventDefault();
$('.flexslider li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
});